# all the theme of moodle not working

Tags: themes, moodle

I have a big problem with theme in moodle site(version 2.2).

I wanted to change some menus and colors and another things in the site theme, so I turned on the server maintenance mode and Theme designer mode.

All that operations disabled the theme. I tried to turn off those choices but nothing happened, the site is still without any theme. I tried to change the theme, but all the themes are not working.

What happened please, how can i solve that?

Comment: Could you navigate to http://<your-site>/theme and a) click "Clear theme caches" and b) type what your current theme is set to?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try.

Turn on debugging (*Site administration > Development > Debugging*), set to "DEVELOPER: extra Moodle debug messages for developers" and check "Display debug messages"
Try and purge the cache (*Site administration > Development > Purge all caches*)
Do you get an error message when you try to purge the cache? If so, can you paste the error?

Do you have enough free disk space on the server? I had this issue when the SAN which stored my moodledata folder was full.

Comment: "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class theme_bootstrap_core_renderer_maintenance in /public_html/moodle/theme/bootstrap/renderers/maintenance_renderer.php on line 49" There is free space on the server--I am able to upload new files to it.